# Android: How to create a XML - based file for the data container, read from file/add content

Tags: java, android, xml, file, android-studio

In the context of a project, i would like to create a data container based on XML-Files.

Every entry should be a XML-File.

For this task i created a new directory which looks as the following:
[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iVFB.png)

In order to fill the DataBase with XML-Files the following should be done:

1. Create a XML-File in the DataBase Folder.
2. Add content to said XML-File.
3. Eventually change things from the XML-File.

**What i tried:**

For 1:

```
int exampleNumber= 1444;
FileOutputStream example = openFileOutput("app/src/main/java/DataBase/FileName.xml", MODE_PRIVATE); 

example.write(exampleNumber);
example.flush();
example.close();
```

**Issue:** Doesn't do anything.

For 2:

```
private String PATH = "app/src/main/java/DataBase/FileName.xml";

public void addToXML(String Text) throws IOException {
String textToAppend = Text;
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.PATH, true));
writer.write(textToAppend);
writer.close();
}
```

**Issue:** For the 2. to work 1. must work. 1->2

For 3:

Same Issue as above

Comment: `app/src/main/java/` are dev directories, you cannot access them while being on the android device

Comment: First Thanks for your contribution! How to achieve the following scenario: while in an android application, user puts an option into a checkbox, this data is saved in a directory->XML File that can be accesed later for parsing etc... How to achieve this kind of thing?

Comment: You sould not be using XML directly yo save and load values, it would be hard to do what you want to do. What you need to use is 'SharedPreference' ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences ) which allow you to store (and of course retrieve them) key-value data.

Comment: Well the thing is, @EnzoCaceres, it is required for them to be XML-Files and also they are going to be later on exported to an external device.

Comment: SharedPreference use a XML based file type, after saving some data, you can easily read it as a raw string file and send it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple code to demonstrate my words. (i have tested it on my Note 9)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    // Keep your preference in memory
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("my_xml_file", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    
    // Change values
    editor.putBoolean("a_boolean_value", true);
    editor.putInt("an_int_value", 42);
    
    // Apply modification to the file
    editor.commit();
    editor.apply();
    
    try { // Read the file as a string and log it
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), readAsString("my_xml_file.xml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String readAsString(String file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(new File(getDataDir(), "shared_prefs"), file));
    // Preference files are stored in: /data/data/<your package>/shared_prefs/<name>.xml
    
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Your method works very well, however is there a possibility to add a Tag of your choice to the XML-documents, something like <description> or <name> etc, bcs, for right now seemingly you can only introduce putInt, putFloat etc. ? @Enzo Caceres

Comment: Thanks you, but sadly no... The shared preference is meant to store data as key-value. You can always use an XML library to save the data in the tree form you want, but you will lose the easiness of the thing. Sorry if this isn't the anwser you were looking for.

Comment: Its ok, i am just looking for a method to write to an XML file as easily as possible

Comment: What about something like that ? https://github.com/jmurty/java-xmlbuilder (but reading will be harder)

Comment: Or you can try serialization libraries, like jackson: https://stackabuse.com/serialize-and-deserialize-xml-in-java-with-jackson/

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your contribution!